# iphone reduce large image loading time

Tags: iphone, uiimage

Anybody know how to load the large image to become a blur image first and then only slowly load the full size of image. This will at least let the user to preview the image first other than waiting for a few second to load the full size image.

Thanks

Comment: Whats this for? Is this a native app? Are you downloading the image off the internet? Is this a web app?

Comment: This is a photo gallery app, just like the photo library in iphone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to prepare two images, one is for blur image, and one is for the full size of image. As for the JPEG image with EXIF, it contains a thumbnail image inside. So the digital camera will show the thumbnail images when browsing.

Comment: Isn't possible to do something like interlaced images?

Comment: interlaced won't reduce your image size, which is the source of the slowness, I think it just lets you (in theory) show the image loading in a progressive fashion. Having two images is probably the way to go: a small image the the iphone can load quickly and with minimal processing, and a larger image you can load later.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I remember in Image processing class, professor told us that when browsing the web, the server would send your browser a blur image A, and another image B, after you getting both, your computer will be doing image computation on A&B to produce an intermediate image C and do computation on A&C produce another image...this procedure goes on for a couple times to get the original image. That's why you are seeing blurred image at the first place. This procedure theoretically reduce image size linearly.